# Perl CGI says request is Bad (malformed multipart POST)

Tags: perl, http, post, cgi

I am sending the following request from Android java agent to Apache/2.4.6 CGI perl script (CGI.pm 4.38 / Perl 5.18.1 on Linux SUSE 13.1). Dumping $cgi shows the following:

```
[Mon Jun 25 12:22:52.025910 2018] [cgi:error] [pid 20515] [client 192.168.0.10:56197] AH01215: $VAR1 = bless( {
[Mon Jun 25 12:22:52.025963 2018] [cgi:error] [pid 20515] [client 192.168.0.10:56197] AH01215:                  'escape' => 1,
[Mon Jun 25 12:22:52.025977 2018] [cgi:error] [pid 20515] [client 192.168.0.10:56197] AH01215:                  '.fieldnames' => {},
[Mon Jun 25 12:22:52.026006 2018] [cgi:error] [pid 20515] [client 192.168.0.10:56197] AH01215:                  '.charset' => 'ISO-8859-1',
[Mon Jun 25 12:22:52.026019 2018] [cgi:error] [pid 20515] [client 192.168.0.10:56197] AH01215:                  'use_tempfile' => 1,
[Mon Jun 25 12:22:52.026031 2018] [cgi:error] [pid 20515] [client 192.168.0.10:56197] AH01215:                  'param' => {},
[Mon Jun 25 12:22:52.026044 2018] [cgi:error] [pid 20515] [client 192.168.0.10:56197] AH01215:                  '.parameters' => [],
[Mon Jun 25 12:22:52.026066 2018] [cgi:error] [pid 20515] [client 192.168.0.10:56197] AH01215:                  '.cgi_error' => '400 Bad request (malformed multipart POST)'
[Mon Jun 25 12:22:52.026076 2018] [cgi:error] [pid 20515] [client 192.168.0.10:56197] AH01215:                }, 'CGI' );
```

When I captured the request using ncat, I see the following, but don't understand what part is bad (please note that ^M is getting added to the headers automatically). Any help is appreciated.

```
POST /cgi-bin/voicerec.cgi HTTP/1.1^M
Accept-Charset: UTF-8^M
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=-----OMT-164386aa112^M
User-Agent: Dalvik/1.6.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.2.2; GT-P5113 Build/JDQ39)^M
Host: 192.168.0.12:55000^M
Connection: Keep-Alive^M
Accept-Encoding: gzip^M
Content-Length: 515^M
^M


-------OMT-164386aa112
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="action"

as_voice_rec
-------OMT-164386aa112
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="S_UID"

a
-------OMT-164386aa112
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="voice"; filename="audiorecrodtest.3gp"
Content-Type: application/x-object
Here goes the voice data file content.-------OMT-164386aa112--
```

Comment: I am comparing my request data against the specifications on [W3.org](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.2) and not seeing any obvious problems with my request format.

Answer (score 1):

```
-------OMT-164386aa112
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="voice"; filename="audiorecrodtest.3gp"
Content-Type: application/x-object
Here goes the voice data file content.-------OMT-164386aa112--
```

There are multiple things wrong with this part: there is no end-of-header marker, i.e. no empty line between header and body. And the MIME boundary `-------OMT-164386aa112--` must start at the beginning of a line.

Comment: thanks for the reply. The last boundary is now a on a new line, but did not make any difference. What is "end-of-header" marker? can you please elaborate.

Comment: @BReddy: *" What is "end-of-header" marker?"* -  To cite myself: *"no end-of-header marker, i.e. __no empty line between header and body__"*

Comment: Thanks again, I saw that suggestion in another post and added 2 empty lines after the header and before the form-data starts. It shows in the request I posted. Am I missing something?

Comment: @BReddy: to cite myself again: *"...multiple things wrong with __this__ part..."*. And I've actually quoted the relevant MIME part. To make it more clear: There should be an empty line before the body if this part, i.e. before "Here goes...". And I really recommended to use some MIME libraries or alternatively study first and implement then the relevant standards instead  of guessing how this might work.